# How to get top left coordinate when the coordinate on circumference of circle is known?

Tags: ios, iphone, math

I have two concentric circles, the distance between is certain constant.
I obtain the coordinate on the circumference of the outer most circle based on the angle obtained when I touch in the circular portion (including the black circle inside).

This is a subclass of `UIControl` and I use touches method to get point on circumference.

I successfully get the exact angle and hence get the exact point on the circumference of the outermost circle.

But I want to place a button on top of the concentric circle such that its diameter = distance_between_concentric_circles + 2 * offset.

This offset is used so that the button edges should come outside the area of concentric circle, like the image below.

[image: Circle button]

And each time I move that button, it should move along the circular path.

Since I do not want to draw, I'm using `UIButton` and image view, and I'm finding it hard to get the top left co-ordinate based on the point on the circumference of the outer most circle and the size of the `UIButton`.

I can move the button but its not correctly placed on the circular path.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get the top left co-ordinate to set the frame of uibutton?

I want to do this without drawing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to not worry about the top left corner, but rather to just set the `center` property (instead of the `frame` property) of the button. It's not hard to calculate the offset to the upper left, but adjusting the `center` property is far more intuitive, IMHO.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to adjust `center` or `frame` coordinates, you could use Quartz 2D to rotate the button about some point on the screen:

- change the button's `anchorPoint`;
- set the `position` of the button to be the point about which you are rotating (and because  and you've set the `anchorPoint`, the button will be appropriately offset from that `position`); and
- rotate it about that anchor point.

So, if you [link the QuartzCore.framework to your project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17), you can then:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) CFTimeInterval startTime;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self rotateButtonAroundPoint];
}

- (void)rotateButtonAroundPoint
{
    // the point about which I'm rotating and at what radius

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
    CGFloat radius = 100.0;

    // now configure the button's layer accordingly

    self.button.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5 + radius / self.button.frame.size.height);
    self.button.layer.position = center;

    // just so I can see what I'm rotating this around

    [self addCircleAt:center radius:5.0 color:[UIColor redColor]];

    // turn on display link to animate it (better than `NSTimer` for animations)

    [self startDisplayLink];
}

- (void)addCircleAt:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius color:(UIColor *)color
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:2.0 * M_PI clockwise:YES];

    layer.path = [path CGPath];
    layer.fillColor = [color CGColor];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
}

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    self.startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    CFTimeInterval elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - _startTime;

    self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(elapsed * 2.0 * M_PI / 5.0); // duration = 5.0 seconds
}
```

I suspect that just changing the `center`/`frame` or doing a translation (rather than this rotation) might be computationally less expensive, but if you want the button to actually rotate as it's spinning around, this is an option, and it enjoys a certain elegance (just set `position` and `anchorPoint` and rotate it about that, not worrying about cartesian coordinates at all).

Comment: Thanks a lot. i changed the radius, such that it was in between the concentric circles to get the co-ordinate on its circumference and set that as the center of the uibutton and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Any point on the circumference of circle with center as origin is denoted by `(r*cos(theta),r*sin*(theta))`
and apart from the origin, any point on circumference will be `(x+r*cos(theta),y+r*sin*(theta))`
`(x,y)` will be the center of the circle, So calculate `(x+r*cos(theta),y+r*sin*(theta))` and set the button center